# "I'm not your teacher. Best of luck though!" in Spanish

Tags: traducción

A teacher in a Spanish-speaking country gave my email address to his/her students, and I'm now inundated with pictures of children doing homework. How do I say something like:

> This isn't the right email address, but good luck on the project!

Google translate says:

> Esta no es la dirección de correo electrónico correcta, ¡pero buena suerte en el proyecto!

Unfortunately, I don't speak any Spanish, and I don't want to accidentally be mean about it. Is that an OK way to put it?

Comment: Wow! What fun! The suggested translation  is fine. It's correct and sounds friendly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The suggested translation is fine and it is polite enough but it won't be enough to stop the emails.

I have the same problem with some guy that has the same name and last name as me.

You could add. **"por favor no envíes más emails a esta dirección porque yo no soy tu profesor"** meaning *"please do not send more emails to this address because I am not your teacher"*.

I also suggest using the block/filter option in your email client since I guess just telling children not to send their homework won't fully work either.

Good luck